# How to call the class choosercolor from module tkinter in python function askcolor?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to call the `askcolor` function to call the color palette:

```
from tkinter import *
colorchooser.askcolor()
```

But I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    colorchooser.askcolor()
NameError: name 'colorchooser' is not defined
```

Comment: see [here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors] why not to use screenshots

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. In your case I would recommend to go through the docs and tutorials and try to grasp the general approach for what are you trying to achieve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using from `tkinter import *` that imports from tkinter all methods and variables (actually all public objects not starting with _), but not its submodules. (you can read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package))

So when you try to call `colorchooser.askcolor()` you have not imported it yet because it's a submodule!

You can change your import and it will resolve to issue!

Try this:

```
from tkinter import colorchooser
colorchooser.askcolor()
```

Hope this helps you!